# Encrypting sensitive data using AES encryption using dynamic Key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption, aes

I am using Angular `cryptoJS` and `AES` to encrypt and decrypt sensitive data and storing in local storage. I am using hard coded 'KEY' for encryption and decryption. `But how do i use dynamic key instead of hard coded key?`

```
setStorageData(storageInfoObj: any){
     let dataobj = {"institutionid":"159198","userimage":"","firstname":""};  
     let d = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(dataobj), "123456").toString(); 
     this.storage.set('deviceinfo', d);

 }

 getStorageData() {
         return this.storage.get('deviceinfo').then((deviceObj:any) => {
            if (deviceObj) {
              try {
                let decrdata = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(deviceObj, "123456");
                return this.encryptDataObj = JSON.parse(decrdata.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
              } catch (err) {

              }
            }

          }
        );
       }
```

Comment: Local Storage is not appropriate for sensitive data of any type, better to store an arbitrary identifier that points to data held on a server behind an authentication layer.

Comment: Ask the user to remember it?

Comment: @Jonas, we can use password as the key for encryption?

Comment: Yes, shure. Thats the sense of encryption.

Comment: @JonasW. As long as we use an appropriate KDF and not the raw password, which I'm *sure* you meant.

Comment: @luke theres a difference between code in production and hobby projects. For learners i think its sufficient to simply use thepassword directly, for code in prod. you are definetly right ;)

Comment: @vishnu please use proper PBKDF and salt to create an encryption key from password. Even for hobby project - learn it right. Doing security wrong is dangerous to learn and people tend to copy/paste code without thinking a lot about it

Comment: @JonasW. Mmmm I disagree.  If you're learning how to do something, shouldn't you learn how to do it properly?  There isn't a single scenario where using a raw password as a key to an encryption algorithm makes sense.